# Prettier removing spaces of HTML element text content

Tags: angular, prettier

I am using the ESLint rule `"prettier/prettier"` in my project. I am using `"parser": "angular"`

Prettier is detecting and removing trailing spaces within the text content in my elements, for example:

```html
<span> text <span>
```

It changes it to:

```html
<span>text<span>
```

Is there any rule or way to disable it without disabling Prettier?

I have tried many rules like `WhitespaceSensitivity` but none seem to fit.

Comment: Doesn't address your question, but changing the spaces to &#32; will prevent them from being removed, as would moving the spaces outside of the span tag (if possible).

Comment: you won't like this comment and I can't give you statistics or any book that mentions this, but it's not common (or even best practice) to rely on spaces before or after the content in ANY html element. It's ok to have spaces, but you should NEVER rely on spaces for styling or layout. So, if you are just trying to give your text some padding on the left and right, you need to change all instances of `<span> text </span>` to something with CSS like `<span style="padding:0 1ch;">text</span>`.

Comment: Christian Legge, how would I change spaces to &#32? Aren't they the same character?

Comment: user3163495, I understand, I appreciate it, it is just something that appears all around my project due to being late with ESLint, so it's a lot of work, but I might just do it manually, thank you a lot!